# NoClassDefFoundException

Tags: android

I am using fragments in Android.I got an `NoClassDefFoundException` while clicking the button. The code given below.

MainActivity.class

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(view.equals(btnLogin)){
        Intent logd=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
        startActivity(logd);
    }
```

Home.class

```
package com.nv.netpos;
import java.util.Stack;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;
public class Home extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    private FragmentTabHost tabHost;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        tabHost=(FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup(getApplicationContext(), getSupportFragmentManager());
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("HOME"),
             Fragment2.class, null);
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("ITEMS"),
                Fragment2.class, null);
}}
```

Comment: Give us the full error?

Comment: post AndroidManifest.xml file, and logcat error also.

Comment: Besides passing `getApplicationContext()` pass `getActivity()`. @jithin

Comment: @jithin can you post your whole logcat error ?

Comment: check imports in your project

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Unable to instantiate activity: Didn't find class on path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273218/android-unable-to-instantiate-activity-didnt-find-class-on-path)

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17273218/1051783

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Go to Project/Properties/Java Build Path/Order and Export -- Make sure there's a check in front of Android Dependencies and the support library, if you use it.Mark all checkboxes.Click on Apply and clean the project.

This worked for me.Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably that you didnt declare `Home` activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

See [AndroidManifest documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) or [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699192/have-you-declared-this-activity-in-your-androidmanifest-xml) to learn how to declare activity in manifest.

Note: as @GrIsHu pointed out in comments, dont use getApplicationContext(), use getApplication() when passing context parameter.