# App Crash due to start of activity that launches asset activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-assets

I am in the learning stage and i am building an app to test system activities. Here's the code for the main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

String tests[] = { "LifeCycleTest", "SingleTouchTest", "MultiTouchTest",
        "KeyTest", "AccelerometerTest", "AssetsTest",
        "ExternalStorageTest", "SoundPoolTest", "MediaPlayerTest",
        "FullScreenTest", "RenderViewTest", "ShapeTest", "BitmapTest",
        "FontTest", "SurfaceViewTest" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tests));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(list, view, position, id);
    String testName = tests[position];
    try {
        Class c = Class.forName("com.ag.systemtests." + testName);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {  e.printStackTrace();  }
}
}
```

When i run the app, it runs fine until i choose the AssestsTest option. The code for the activity AssetsTest is:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AssetsTest extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        setContentView(textView);

        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();


        InputStream input;
        try {
            input = assetManager.open("myawesometext.txt");

            int size = input.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            input.read(buffer);
            input.close();

            // byte buffer into a string
            String text = new String(buffer);

            textView.setText(text);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The app crashes when i chose this activity. The error is coming on the startActivity(intent) line. What do i do?

The logcat is:

```
10-03 00:15:59.186  24699-24699/com.androidgames.systemtests I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
10-03 00:15:59.232  24699-24710/com.androidgames.systemtests I/art﹕ Debugger is no longer active
10-03 00:15:59.392  24699-24722/com.androidgames.systemtests D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
10-03 00:15:59.402  24699-24699/com.androidgames.systemtests D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
10-03 00:15:59.444  24699-24722/com.androidgames.systemtests I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.04
    Build Date: 04/06/15 Mon
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch:
    Local Patches:
    Reconstruct Branch:
10-03 00:15:59.446  24699-24722/com.androidgames.systemtests I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-03 00:15:59.508  24699-24722/com.androidgames.systemtests D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
10-03 00:16:09.783  24699-24699/com.androidgames.systemtests D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
10-03 00:16:09.801  24699-24699/com.androidgames.systemtests E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.androidgames.systemtests, PID: 24699
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.androidgames.systemtests/com.androidgames.systemtests.AssetsTest}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
            at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1868)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1568)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3755)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3716)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4036)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3998)
            at com.androidgames.systemtests.AndroidBasicsStarter.onListItemClick(AndroidBasicsStarter.java:32)
            at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3053)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3860)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Comment: what is the crash. paste the logcat.

Comment: I've posted the logcat.

Comment: have you declared assetstest activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @PräTîkTank that's not working. It's showing the textView of setContentView(textView) in red as textView is not initialized. The AssetsTest activity is running fine if it is run as a seperate app.

Comment: @Tauqir Amazingly caught. That was it. It wasn't declared in the manifest file. Thanks a ton. I've been at it for about an hour. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this `<activity android:name=".AssetsTest"></activity>` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

for reference visit 
[have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699192/have-you-declared-this-activity-in-your-androidmanifest-xml)