# Unfortunately, Todo has stopped

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Can someone please assist me, no mater what i do i can't get around this problem of the app not working. I am using Android studio.

My `Logcat`

```
 10-23 07:29:21.312  31399-31399/org.jaco.todo D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
 10-23 07:29:21.512  31399-31402/org.jaco.todo D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 82K, 2% free 11049K/11271K, paused 11ms+0ms, total 16ms
 10-23 07:29:21.532  31399-31399/org.jaco.todo D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
 10-23 07:29:21.536  31399-31399/org.jaco.todo W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa62d9288)
 10-23 07:29:21.540  31399-31399/org.jaco.todo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.jaco.todo/org.jaco.todo.TodoActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: To use this functionality, add this to your AndroidManifest.xml:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: To use this functionality, add this to your AndroidManifest.xml:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
            at com.parse.Parse.requirePermission(Parse.java:495)
            at com.parse.ParseCommandCache.runEventuallyAsync(ParseCommandCache.java:250)
            at com.parse.ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(ParseAnalytics.java:61)
            at com.parse.ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(ParseAnalytics.java:32)
            at org.jaco.todo.TodoActivity.onCreate(TodoActivity.java:41)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            ... 11 more
10-23 07:29:58.452  31399-31399/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 31399 SIG: 9
```

My `TodoActivity.java`

```
        public class TodoActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

            private EditText mTaskInput;
            private ListView mListView;
            private TaskAdapter mAdapter;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_todo);

                Parse.initialize(this, "9YsgDgjMOqulfH9JYXVWZG5a6EBVf1SbMyz7gXH4", "CZ60kHo0V9cG190DAoIhB781BL3mRfdy6FSSPy6D");
                ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
                ParseObject.registerSubclass(Task.class);

                ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                if(currentUser == null){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }

                mAdapter = new TaskAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Task>());

                mTaskInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.task_input);
                mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.task_list);
                mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

                updateData();
            }

            public void updateData(){
                ParseQuery<Task> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Task.class);
                query.whereEqualTo("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
                query.setCachePolicy(CachePolicy.CACHE_THEN_NETWORK);
                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Task>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(List<Task> tasks, ParseException error) {
                        if(tasks != null){
                            mAdapter.clear();
                            for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
                                mAdapter.add(tasks.get(i));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            public void createTask(View v) {
                if (mTaskInput.getText().length() > 0){
                    Task t = new Task();
                    t.setACL(new ParseACL(ParseUser.getCurrentUser()));
                    t.setUser(ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
                    t.setDescription(mTaskInput.getText().toString());
                    t.setCompleted(false);
                    t.saveEventually();
                    mAdapter.insert(t, 0);
                    mTaskInput.setText("");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.todo, menu);
                return true;
            }

            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.sign_in:
                        ParseUser.logOut();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Task task = mAdapter.getItem(position);
                TextView taskDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.task_description);

                task.setCompleted(!task.isCompleted());

                if(task.isCompleted()){
                    taskDescription.setPaintFlags(taskDescription.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                }else{
                    taskDescription.setPaintFlags(taskDescription.getPaintFlags() & (~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
                }

                task.saveEventually();
            }

        }
```

my `activity_todo.xml`

```
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            tools:context=".TodoActivity" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/task_input"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:hint="input_hint">
                    <requestFocus />
                </EditText>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/submit_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="createTask"
                    android:text="submit_button" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/task_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="org.jaco.todo" >

            <application
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
                <activity
                    android:name=".TodoActivity"
                    android:label="@string/app_name" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
            </application>

        </manifest>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `IllegalStateException: To use this functionality, add this to your AndroidManifest.xml:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Comment: The exception log clearly says that you have to add `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission to your manifest

Comment: i tried it, but it don't work

Comment: i have a new error now, it says :                                  Unable to find explicit activity class {org.jaco.todo/org.jaco.todo.LoginActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 5):

Add your `TodoActivity` class with package name in your `Manifest` File and also add next permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: i added it but now it says :                             android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {org.jaco.todo/org.jaco.todo.LoginActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Have you declared TodoActivity with package name in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @Jaco read and take in the errors, they are very descriptive. Also if you search for them you will find help on them. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699192/have-you-declared-this-activity-in-your-androidmanifest-xml

Comment: @Jaco the second error is about **LoginActivity** not *TodoActivity*. You need to declare **all** your activities in manifest file.