# Intent nullPointer Exception

Tags: android, android-intent

I know here exists a lot of topics with this header but I am new on android developing and tried many things but don't reach a solution.

I have a MainClass with a TextView. The MainClass calls a Method in a second Class ("Check"). The second Class should only create an intent with a string which i print out in textview of the mainClass. (Later it should be more complex but first I have to get that).

Here my Code of MainClass:

```
    package com.projektarbeit;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        public static TextView output = null;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            //Variable initialisieren
            output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
            //App gestartet ausgeben
            output.setText("App started");

            Check check1 = new Check();
            check1.doCheck();

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String myString = intent.getStringExtra("Test");
            output.setText(myString);
        }
    }
```

Here my Code of CheckClass:

```
    package com.projektarbeit;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;

    public class Check extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_check);
        }

        public void doCheck (){

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Test", "This is a test");
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    }
```

Am I totally wrong or what is my mistake?

Comment: Which is your launcher activity? Check  or MainActivity?

Comment: Your way is not proper. Describe here your need first.

Comment: you can use startActivityforResult see this example http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: i think because of its context its throwing null pointer exception .Can you share crashlog

Answer (score 4):

Why you are using Intent, What exactly you want to do?

If you really want to check only string then following Piece of code will work:

```
 public String doCheck (){ 

   return "This is a test";

 }
```

And to set this text in your textView you just have to call this method like this:

```
    output.setText(check1.doCheck());
```

Comment: because the method doCheck is in an other acivity than the TextView. And I want to handle the result in the view of the MainActivity!

Answer (score 0):

```
Check check1 = new Check();  
check1.doCheck();
```

You should not instantiate an `Activity`.
To start `Check` from your `MainActivity` you should do something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Check.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Also, as **Md. Dinar** has suggested, don't forget to [declare the Activity on your AndroidManifest file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699192/have-you-declared-this-activity-in-your-androidmanifest-xml/).

Comment: I tried it like you promt here but than the Textview is emtpy :(

Answer (score -1):

Have you added your activities in android manifest? If yes Try

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Check.this, MainActivity.class);
```

instead of

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
```

Comment: If activity is not added to AndroidManifest.xml then error will be "ClassNotFound" not "NullPointer".