# Android - Activity not found exception error

Tags: android, android-activity, activitynotfoundexception

I get the following error:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {ie.ittralee.finalyeartest.finalyeartest/ie.ittralee.finalyeartest.finalyeartest.WiFiDirectActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Now I believe that 'WifiDirectActivity should be right after the first 'finalyeartest' in the path.  Not sure why there is two?

WifiDirectActivity.java

```
import ie.ittralee.finalyeartest.finalyeartest.DeviceListFragment.DeviceActionListener;

import static ie.ittralee.finalyeartest.finalyeartest.R.id.frag_list;


public class WiFiDirectActivity extends Activity implements ChannelListener, DeviceActionListener {

    public static final String TAG = "LightShare";
    private WifiP2pManager manager;
    private boolean isWifiP2pEnabled = false;
    private boolean retryChannel = false;

    private final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    private Channel channel;
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = null;

    /**
     * @param isWifiP2pEnabled the isWifiP2pEnabled to set
     */
    public void setIsWifiP2pEnabled(boolean isWifiP2pEnabled) {
        this.isWifiP2pEnabled = isWifiP2pEnabled;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

...More code
```

If you need any extra code let me know.  Below the above class is just some Wifi connection stuff, not related.  Hopefully not...

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ie.ittralee.finalyeartest.finalyeartest">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Google Play filtering -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi.direct" android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Light Share"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ShareFilesActivity"></activity>

        <!-- Used for transferring files  after a successful connection -->
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".FileTransferService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Added manifest above.

Comment: Add `<activity android:name=".WiFiDirectActivity"></activity>` in `AndroidManifest` inside application tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [...have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699192/have-you-declared-this-activity-in-your-androidmanifest-xml)

Comment: Yup just did it there.  It works.  Totally bypassed that somehow.  Thanks for the time, matey!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your activity to the manifest like this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Light Share"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ShareFilesActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".WiFiDirectActivity">

    <!-- Used for transferring files  after a successful connection -->
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".FileTransferService" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

The fix was just adding the activity in my manifest.  Totally bypassed that somehow.

```
 <activity android:name=".WiFiDirectActivity"></activity>
```

Answer (score -1):

did you declare your activity in AndroidManifest.xml?
Something like the following:

```
<activity android:name=".WiFiDirectActivity"      
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
</activity>
```

Comment: I just see it now. I apparently did not. I'll do it now and see if that fixes my problem. 2 minutes