# Have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? (Android Studio) 2018

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a problem with just one list. What happens is that I want 10 items to come out, but only one appears.

I think it's because of my activity and fragment, but what code do you have to put it? Besides, I get an error in the "logcat" that says "have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?"

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Logcat

```
08-30 22:31:23.981 2603-2664/? W/AASAInstall:  updated apk:com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer   uid:-1
08-30 22:31:28.391 2603-2664/? W/PackageManager: Code path for pkg : com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer changing from /data/app/com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer-2 to /data/app/com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer-1
08-30 22:31:28.391 2603-2664/? W/PackageManager: Resource path for pkg : com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer changing from /data/app/com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer-2 to /data/app/com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer-1
08-30 22:31:30.076 2603-2603/? E/SDAgentPackageStateReceiver: Not going to handle 'com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer'!
08-30 22:31:30.881 2603-2603/? E/SDAgentPackageStateReceiver: Not going to handle 'com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer'!
08-30 22:31:30.946 4206-4206/? E/SPPClientService: [PackageInfoChangeReceiver] [handlePkgRemovedEvent] PackageName : com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer, true, false
    [PackageInfoChangeReceiver] [handlePkgRemovedEvent] Ignore Replacing case
08-30 22:31:31.426 2603-2603/? W/BackupManagerService: Removing schedule queue dupe of com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer
08-30 22:31:32.036 3057-3057/? E/Launcher.Model: onPackageChanged :com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer
08-30 22:31:32.746 4293-4293/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer, PID: 4293
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer/com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer.FragmentActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer/com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer.RecycleViewFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3133)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3243)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1718)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6917)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
     Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer/com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer.RecycleViewFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1837)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1534)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4125)
        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4072)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:732)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4396)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4364)
        at com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:15)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3243) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1718) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6917) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
08-30 22:31:32.851 2603-3486/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity 1 com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer/.FragmentActivity
08-30 22:31:33.661 2603-2652/? W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{1fa90a00 u0 com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer/.FragmentActivity t12 f}
08-30 22:31:34.691 2847-2847/? W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer: Resource ID #0x0
08-30 22:31:38.316 4275-4275/? W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer: Resource ID #0x0
08-30 22:33:00.406 4941-4941/? W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer: Resource ID #0x0
08-30 22:33:28.741 5447-5447/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer, PID: 5447
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer/com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer.FragmentActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer/com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer.RecycleViewFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3133)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3243)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1718)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6917)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
     Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer/com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer.RecycleViewFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1837)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1534)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4125)
        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4072)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:732)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4396)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4364)
        at com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:15)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3243) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1718) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6917) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
08-30 22:33:28.746 2603-3091/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity 1 com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer/.FragmentActivity
08-30 22:33:29.276 2603-2652/? W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{2c42a0c9 u0 com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer/.FragmentActivity t13 f}
08-30 22:33:30.301 2847-2847/? W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer: Resource ID #0x0
08-30 22:35:54.861 5726-5726/? W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer: Resource ID #0x0
08-30 22:41:05.371 6355-6355/? W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer: Resource ID #0x0
08-30 22:59:26.871 11998-11998/? W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer: Resource ID #0x0
08-30 23:03:33.836 13685-13685/? W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer: Resource ID #0x0
```

*activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_que_cambia"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/boton_flotante"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:layout_gravity = "start"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:itemIconTint="#f0f0"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image]

*Here is my Activity code

[image]

*"AndroidManifest.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">



    <activity android:name=".My_fragment_activity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

*activity_note_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:id="@+id/cardview">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/texto"
            android:text="Hola texto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titulo"
            android:text="Hola titulo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/body"
            android:text="Hola body"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/xd"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/yopyop" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

*NotesAdapter.java

```
package com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer.Adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer.POJOS.Note;
import com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer.R;

import java.util.List;

public class NotesAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.ViewHolder>{ 

Context context;
List<Note> noteList;

public NotesAdapter(Context context, List<Note> noteList){
    this.context = context;
    this.noteList = noteList;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_note_item, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //Todo_esto se aplica al TextView, y es obvio de que el TextView SOLO recibe texto(cadenas);
    holder.texto.setText(String.valueOf(noteList.get(position).getId()));
    holder.tituto.setText(String.valueOf(noteList.get(position).getTitle()));
    holder.body.setText(String.valueOf(noteList.get(position).getBody()));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return noteList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{ 

    CardView cardView;
    TextView texto, tituto, body;
    ImageView imageView;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
        texto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.texto);
        tituto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
        body = itemView.findViewById(R.id.body);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.xd);
    }
}

}
```

*RecycleViewFragment.java

```
package com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer.Adapters.NotesAdapter;
import com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer.POJOS.Note;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class RecycleViewFragment extends Fragment{

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<Note> lista;
private NotesAdapter adapter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView;
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recyclerview, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_recyclerview);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    //Método donde se inicializa los datos
    initializedData();
    adapter = new NotesAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), lista);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void initializedData(){
    lista = new ArrayList<>();
    lista.add(new Note(1,"Nota 1", "Este es el teto de la nota 1"));
    lista.add(new Note(2,"Nota 2", "Este es el teto de la nota 2"));
    lista.add(new Note(3,"Nota 3", "Este es el teto de la nota 3"));
    lista.add(new Note(4,"Nota 4", "Este es el teto de la nota 4"));
    lista.add(new Note(5,"Nota 5", "Este es el teto de la nota 5"));
    lista.add(new Note(6,"Nota 6", "Este es el teto de la nota 6"));
    lista.add(new Note(7,"Nota 7", "Este es el teto de la nota 7"));
    lista.add(new Note(8,"Nota 8", "Este es el teto de la nota 8"));
    lista.add(new Note(9,"Nota 9", "Este es el teto de la nota 9"));
    lista.add(new Note(10,"Nota 10", "Este es el teto de la nota 10"));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

}
```

*fragment_recyclerview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you are trying to pass a fragment to `startActivity`. `startActivity` can start only activities.

Comment: What should I do friend @Vladyslav Matviienko?

Comment: probaby pass through some basic Android activities and Fragments training to understand how Activities and Fragments work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [...have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699192/have-you-declared-this-activity-in-your-androidmanifest-xml)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Firstly, do not use the name of your class as `FragmentActivity` ... It's an inbuilt class. So change it to something else then replace it in manifest.

Secondly,

remove

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

from your,

```
<activity android:name=".FragmentActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

`<intent-filter>` only for one activity is enough, or else it will create many icons for different activities.

Thirdly,

write `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` as shown below:

```
public void initializedData(){
    lista = new ArrayList<>();
    lista.add(new Note(1,"Nota 1", "Este es el teto de la nota 1"));
    lista.add(new Note(2,"Nota 2", "Este es el teto de la nota 2"));
    lista.add(new Note(3,"Nota 3", "Este es el teto de la nota 3"));
    lista.add(new Note(4,"Nota 4", "Este es el teto de la nota 4"));
    lista.add(new Note(5,"Nota 5", "Este es el teto de la nota 5"));
    lista.add(new Note(6,"Nota 6", "Este es el teto de la nota 6"));
    lista.add(new Note(7,"Nota 7", "Este es el teto de la nota 7"));
    lista.add(new Note(8,"Nota 8", "Este es el teto de la nota 8"));
    lista.add(new Note(9,"Nota 9", "Este es el teto de la nota 9"));
    lista.add(new Note(10,"Nota 10", "Este es el teto de la nota 10"));
    ........ (Write here)
}
```

Also, You cannot call a Fragment class using an Intent in your MainActivity.class, Use like this:

```
Fragment fragment = new RecyclerViewFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragment_frame, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

and remove intent from MainActivity's onCreate()

then, change this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_que_cambia"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/boton_flotante"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

To:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>
```

Finally,

In your onCreate():

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

That's it

Hope it helps.

Comment: Same error? Also can you please update the code with the changes I've suggested as an Image please?

Comment: @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal Hey bro, You can't call a Fragment class with using a Intent from your main Activity.

Comment: @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal Please paste your activity_main.xml full file code

Comment: wow and what other code should correct or add friend @Umang Burman?

Comment: @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal One more last thing after that, show me your activity_main.xml

Comment: @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal Bro, I've updated my answer.. see the last part and do the necessary changes. Update me if it works.

Comment: I already execute !!! More mistakes came out, but solve them. Thank you

Comment: @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal Please consider accepting the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Please check below snippet, there is minor mistake you have made. 
If unclear let me know.**

> **RecycleViewFragment.java** has a minor change as below.

```
package com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer.Adapters.NotesAdapter;
import com.example.gonzalo.testdrawer.POJOS.Note;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class RecycleViewFragment extends Fragment{

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<Note> lista;
private NotesAdapter adapter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView;
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recyclerview, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_recyclerview);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    //Método donde se inicializa los datos

    adapter = new NotesAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), lista);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter); 

//---------------- Change is here ------------------------------
     initializedData();   // call this function after initialization and assignment of adapter.
}

public void initializedData(){
    lista = new ArrayList<>();
    lista.add(new Note(1,"Nota 1", "Este es el teto de la nota 1"));
    lista.add(new Note(2,"Nota 2", "Este es el teto de la nota 2"));
    lista.add(new Note(3,"Nota 3", "Este es el teto de la nota 3"));
    lista.add(new Note(4,"Nota 4", "Este es el teto de la nota 4"));
    lista.add(new Note(5,"Nota 5", "Este es el teto de la nota 5"));
    lista.add(new Note(6,"Nota 6", "Este es el teto de la nota 6"));
    lista.add(new Note(7,"Nota 7", "Este es el teto de la nota 7"));
    lista.add(new Note(8,"Nota 8", "Este es el teto de la nota 8"));
    lista.add(new Note(9,"Nota 9", "Este es el teto de la nota 9"));
    lista.add(new Note(10,"Nota 10", "Este es el teto de la nota 10"));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

}
```